# JQuery Как узнать количество элементов?

Tags: jquery

Есть элементы, которые были перемещены с помощью `drag'n drop`. Нужно сделать, чтобы перетаскивался только один элемент, т.е. если перетащить картинку красной шляпы, то при перетаскивании картинки синей шляпы, красная шляпа вернулась.

```js
var drop = $(".drop"),
  maxSize = 3000000; //300 Kb
//проверка drag'n drop
if (typeof(window.FileReader) == 'undefined') {
  drop.text('Не поддерживается браузером!');
  drop.addClass('error');
}
//проверка drag'n drop


drop[0].ondragover = function() {
  drop.addClass("hover");
  return false;
}

drop[0].ondragleave = function() {
  drop.removeClass("hover");
  return false;
}

drop[0].ondrop = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  drop.removeClass('hover');
  drop.addClass('ondrop');

  var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];


  if (file.size > maxSize) {
    drop.text('Файл слишком большой!');
    drop.addClass('error');
    return false;
  } else if (file.type != "image/jpeg") {
    alert("only jpeg or jpg !!!");
    drop.removeClass("ondrop");
  } else {
    //            $.ajax({
    //                url: "getImg.php",
    //                data: file,
    //                success: function(file){
    //                    imgField.html(file);
    //                }
    //            })
  }
};
//ЗАГРУЗКА КАРТИНКИ  

//ВЫБОР АКСЕССУАРА 
// Переменные
var acs = $(".accessories"),
  imgField = $("#image"),
  plus = $("#plus"),
  minus = $("#minus"),
  acsW = acs.width(),
  acsH = acs.height();

acs.draggable({
  zIndex: 100,
  revert: function(event) {
    $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    };
    return !event;
  }
});

$(".picture").droppable({
  drop: alert(acs.length)
});
```

```css
.picture {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="hat" class="grid_12 submenu center">
  <img src="images/accessories/HAT_1.png" class="accessories" />
  <img src="images/accessories/HAT_2.png" class="accessories" />
  <img src="images/accessories/HAT_3.png" class="accessories" />
  <img src="images/accessories/HAT_4.png" class="accessories" />
</div>

<div class="picture"></div>

<!-- Что бы ошибка не вылазила :) -->
<noscript class="drop"></noscript>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, что бы мы могли дать конкретный ответ.

Comment: @Yuri Что Вам непонятно? Красная шляпа, синяя шляпа - все ясно :)

Comment: Какой плагин вы используете для перетаскивания, куда вы перетаскиваете и как вы это делаете и т. д.

Comment: А если зелёную шляпу перетащить, должна вернуться синяя? Верно?

Comment: @vp_arth, а вы не уловили логику? Шляпы должны возвращаться, когда ты берёшь другую..

Comment: @Yuri это если у пользователя одна голова

Comment: @Igor, всё равно на этот вопрос невозможно объективно ответить без кода.

Comment: @Yuri, почему? ответ на вопрос - свойство `length`

Comment: @vp_arth, ответ должен содержать код решения (пример) и, или объяснение решения, или комментарии в коде (что в принципе одно и тоже). Что вы сейчас напишите в ответе? Используйте `length` и будьте счастливы?

Comment: извините) сейчас будет код)

Comment: немогу length додумать(

Comment: `drop.children('.accessories').length`?

Comment: не помогло, так как при перетаскивании элемент не перемещяет свое местоположение в коде

Comment: @aslan, а почему бы вам не создать переменную, в которую бы вы записывали элемент, который перетащен в данный момент; и когда вы перетаскиваете новый, то тот возвращается. Возврат по-моему есть в JqueryUI